# Cognos: Get the associated IDs as CSV in an attribute

Tags: csv, cognos

I am building a report in IBM Cognos Report Studio, I need to get the list of associated records as CSV in an attribute. For example: I have the following tables Risks & Controls

```
--------   |  ---------   
Risks      |  Controls    
---  ----  |  ---  -----  
rID  Name  |  cID  Name   
---  ----  |  ---  -----  
R1   rnm1  |  C1   cnm1   
R2   rnm2  |  C2   cnm2   
           |  C3   cnm3   
           |  C4   cnm4
```

And lets say following relation exist between the two tables.

```
--------------- 
Risk_x_Controls 
--------------- 
rID  cID        
---  ---         
R1   C1         
R1   C2
R2   C1         
R2   C2         
R2   C3
```

How can I get the above relationships represented as CSV value in an attribute like

```
--------------- 
Risk_x_Controls 
--------------- 
rID  cIDs        
---  ----         
R1   C1, C2
R2   C1, C2, C3
```

The above is pretty easy to accomplish in SAS. For Cognos Report Studio, I have no clue. F1! F1!

Comment: It's kind of a pain, but you can do it using a repeater combined with a master/detail relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't see how can you do it on Report Studio side.

Try to do it on DB side.
Build a query using LISTAGG (or STRAGG) on Oracle or XML Path Solution on MS SQL then use it in RS.

You can do it if you have access to Framework manager or have rights to use SQL queries in Report Studio.